# How to define the borders for an entire column with spreadsheetgear?

Tags: spreadsheetgear

I know how to define the style of the border for a Cell, like that for example:

```
Dim border As SpreadsheetGear.IBorder

border = sheet.Cells(1, column).Borders(SpreadsheetGear.BordersIndex.EdgeRight)

border.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Black
border.LineStyle = SpreadsheetGear.LineStyle.Continuous
border.Weight = SpreadsheetGear.BorderWeight.Medium
```

This is working.

What I want to do now is to define the style of the border ***for an entire column***. Exactly like what I would obtain if in Excel I ***select the column by clicking on the header and define the border attributes***.

I've tried to do it on this range:

```
border = sheet.Cells(1, column).Columns.Borders(SpreadsheetGear.BordersIndex.EdgeRight)
```

The code doen't crash, but it doesn't add a border.

Anybody can help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of Columns, try EntireColumn:

```
border = sheet.Cells(1, column).EntireColumn.Borders(SpreadsheetGear.BordersIndex.EdgeRight)
```